# How to get id multiple li for check repeat id

Tags: jquery, html

my code http://jsfiddle.net/iwebsmile/rbfr6hvh/

I have input nummber

```
<input type="number" id="r1">
<input type="number" id="r2">
```

after change number create new row

```
$(".list").append("<div class='row' id="+r1+">bbb</div>");
```

result:

```
<li class="list">
    <div class="row" id="r1">1</div>
</li>
```

when first change on number id="r2" result:

```
<li class="list">
    <div class="row" id="r1">1</div>
    <div class="row" id="r2">1</div>
</li>
```

after second change, I need not repeat id

```
<li class="list">
    <div class="row" id="r1">1</div>
    <div class="row" id="r2">1</div>
    <div class="row" id="r2">2</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to append indefinitely, or just update the count?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have to add tags with id. In some situation, there are repeat id in html makes javascript getElementById error. Is there any tools or packages I can **manage html id** ? We use vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Make global variable idCount and increment it on every new row:

```
var idCount = 1;
```

make function of bellow code. and then call that function.

```
function AddRow(){
idCount++;
$(".list").append("<div class='row' id='r"+ idCount +"'>bbb</div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The input element and the new `div` can't have the same id, also check whether such an element exists

```js
function selectGuest() {
    $(".checkGuest").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() > 0) {
            var getID = this.id;
            var getGuest = $(this).val();

            var $el = $('#e' + getID);
            if (!$el.length) {
                $el = $('<div />', {
                    className: 'row',
                    id: 'e' + getID
                }).appendTo('.list');
            }
            $el.text(getGuest);
        }
    });
}
selectGuest();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1 : <input type="number" id="r1" class="checkGuest" value="0">
<br/>
2 : <input type="number" id="r2" class="checkGuest" value="0">
<div class="list"></div>
```